# Numerical Java Libraries

Tags: java, numerical

Most of my code is in Java. For standardized algorithms: matrix operations, FFT, ... I would prefer to not use my own pure Java implementations, and are perfectly happy using unsafe FFI/JNI calls.

What are the libraries I should look into?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you moderators close these questions?  This was useful.

Comment: Ok, I know why, but you shouldn't close them, because the answers can be useful to people.  Just seeing which answer has the most upvotes is a good indicator of what is the most standard library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[CERN's colt library](http://acs.lbl.gov/~hoschek/colt/)

> Colt provides a set of Open Source Libraries for High Performance Scientific and Technical Computing in Java.

Comment: it is worth noting to note that colt library is currently in the process of being integrated (at least a part of it) in commons-math

Answer (score 9):

[Apache commons-math](http://commons.apache.org/math/)

> Commons Math is a library of lightweight, self-contained mathematics and statistics components addressing the most common problems not available in the Java programming language

Answer (score 1):

For Specialised numerics computation look at the General Numerics section of **[NIST](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/#libraries)**

Answer (score 1):

[JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) is a matrix library in Java. It is very easy to use.

Also, Colt has a [parallel](http://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt) version.

Answer (score 0):

[SuanShu](http://nm.dev/) is a Java numerical and statistical library. It supports also parallel computing.